# Running Background service and provide REST API Interface to get data from services in .netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing a application which have multiple endpoints e.g. (`http://localhost:5000/radio`, `http://localhost:5000/Location` etc.) for which I am creating multiple controllers.

But for each controller I want to run Background service. Each controller will be using independent service to get data whenever request comes through REST interface.

I am not sure how to run Background services in .NET Core 3.1. I am looking to derive my Service class from `BackgroundService` to get this functionality.

But all the service has different behavior e.g.

- Timer based
- Waiting for callback event to process data
- One of the service has functionality which reads data from the file whenever some request comes at the REST Framework

It will be great if anyone can provide some insight on this scenario or show some sample code.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good article in the docs that goes over [how to setup background tasks with IHostedService and BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice).

There is also a .NET Core library called [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for working with background tasks which might help.

Comment: Thanks Rosco , Actually i don't want to use hangfire library . So do you think IHostedService can solve my issue and also to call these services from the controllers  I think I should create service member inside all the controllers . Actually I didn't find any sample app  with REST APi and background service running together.

Comment: @sumit these hosted services are transient in nature, so when it is injected into your controller you would be working with a new instance.